# react-native numeric type change returnKeyType

Tags: react-native

I want to add returnKeyType="next" to TextInput keyboardType='numeric', by default on the right there is a 
erase button and on the left . is it possible to add another button ?

Comment: could you show a more exhaustive example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use the prop [`returnKeyType='next'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#returnkeytype) for it. Since the keyboard is native therefore you need to change the native code to add another button.

Answer (score 0):

We can't add next button to numeric but if we can add done button above the keyboard in ios

```
returnKeyType={'done'}
keyboardType="number-pad"
```